# Issues with estimating the sparse inverse covariance matrix with Glasso

Tags: r, normal-distribution, optimization, covariance, convergence

I am trying to estimate the sparse inverse covariance matrix of my gaussian graphical model. I installed the `glasso` package in R and tried out some examples.

After that I ran the `glasso` software on my own data. So I fed it my empirical covariance matrix. However, it seems to get stuck and doesn't give me the results. So I was wondering if I was running the software incorrectly.

I followed this manual: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glasso/glasso.pdf

So if `S` is my empirical covariance matrix. I just ran the following:

```
a <- glasso(S, rho=.01, trace=TRUE)
# outer loop, m = 1
# outer loop, m = 2
```

After the above, it gets stuck.

I am attaching my empirical covariance matrix as well which I feed to the software.

http://rapidshare.com/files/141198734/emp_covariance_matrix.mat

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or warnings?

Comment: @Stijn No. But 6 hours is too long isn't it ?

Comment: Could you export the .mat to a .csv file or something? I want take a look but I'm having trouble exporting .mat in R (and I don't have Matlab).

Comment: I just checked the empirical covariance matrix provided; it is not a valid covariance matrix as it is *not* non-negative definite.  It has quite a few obviously negative eigenvalues (by obviously negative I mean values that are not negative due to machine precision alone as it can happen with PSD matrices, you have $\lambda$'s that equate -0.10078 or -0.22327). I am surprised that you don't get an error-message actually by `glasso` about that. (@Stijn: Use `R.matlab`'s function `readMat()` it works fine for simple .mat files)

Answer (score 0):

Did you standardized data before estimation of covariance matrix? Standardization is necessary before you run glasso, though there may be exceptions ( however, I am not sure about those ocassions). Other option may be estimate covarience matrix and then transform it into correlation matrix. Then run glasso and see the result. Hope it works.